# Testing controller's `new` action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've been testing this controller's `new` and still not passing the test. That's what I have:

`spec` file:

```
......
  describe 'GET #new' do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :new
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

controller file

```
def new
      @item = Item.new
      10.times do
        items.checks.build
      end
  end
```

How should i write a test for `new` action ?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting from rspec?

Comment: @Ren, its just not passing

Comment: are you sure the new action works correctly?

Comment: @Ren, it does, have tried it in console

Comment: Are you sure that you get a 200 code and not a 304? (not modified)